# Creating a shortcode in a plugin that includes JS

Tags: shortcode

I use a lot of embedded tweets on my site. The script always gets stripped out. I added Twitter's code to my theme, but it doesn't work with infinite scroll. So I'd like to make a shortcode that will import the needed script from Twitter.

Please take a look at what I've got below. I can't get it to work and I'm not sure what's wrong. Thanks.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Tweet Shortcode
Description: Use [tweet] to insert the Twitter embed javascript so it won't be stripped from your post.
Author: Nate Hill
Version: 0.1
*/

add_shortcode( 'tweet', 'tweets' );
function tweet_code( $atts ) {
$tweet_text = <<<'EOD'
<!-- Tweet JS. Do not edit. -->
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"  TYPE="text/javascript" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- end  Tweet JS tag -->
EOD;
return $tweet_text;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enqueue Scripts / Styles when shortcode is present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present)

Comment: except this question was written one year after the "duplicate" you mentioned...

Answer (score 2):

Hook function name should be same. You are using "tweets" function name as a parameter for the [add_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) function but actual function name in your code is "tweet_code" so it should be "tweets" as shown in the following code.

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'tweet', 'tweets' );
function tweets( $atts ) {
$tweet_text = <<<'EOD'
<!-- Tweet JS. Do not edit. -->
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"  TYPE="text/javascript" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- end  Tweet JS tag -->
EOD;
return $tweet_text;
}
?>
```

For more information on add_shortcode function visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

Comment: Your code is line for line identical to the OP's code, except for the indentation ([which breaks the heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)).

Comment: @s_ha_dum by mistakenly i forgot to change function name. Now i have changed it. Thanks for letting me know it.

Comment: No problem, but the indentation still breaks the heredoc.

Comment: Great, thanks! I made sure the name was the same and it's working perfectly now. Cheers!

Comment: @user1573016 You are Welcome. Accept the answer if it worked for you.