# style css to header for shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

We have some shortcodes which are generating CSS styles. there are like options ("Title color, Title box border color,font-size, font-weight").

When user setup the options, it will be generated before the shortcode code started.

### ex)

```
<html>
<head>
.................. (some style, js) .................. 
/* I want to put all of css styles into head tag from into body tags */
</head>
<body>
  <style type="text/css">
   .sc_title {color:#fff; font-weight:600;}
  </style>

  <div class="sc_wrap">
   <h1 class="sc_title">Hello This is the title</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you may know **this is illegal rule for W3C. style tags have to be in "head" tag.**

**Is there anyway to put them into header tags when css styles have been generated from shortcodes?**

I have seen some tips or tutorial saying that I should use wp enqueue style. I don't think it's possible to create each .css files for each shortcodes.

Please advise us if we have missed something or if you have any good idea.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enqueue Scripts / Styles when shortcode is present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present)

Answer (score -1):

You can insert any code in the header by hooking an action.

**header.php**

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'iulia_example' );

function iulia_example() {

    echo '<style type="text/css">
   .sc_title {color:#fff; font-weight:600;}
  </style>';

}
```

the result will be : the style inserted just above `</head>`

Comment: thanks you for your comment. however, the "css" is in body tag. the css style gets variables from shortcodes which are in body. I believe and tested that wp_head is Not working in body.

Comment: Hey iulia, OP is asking for shortcode styles, can you please address that.