# Pass Shortcode Attribute to footer Script

Tags: functions, shortcode, customization

I am trying to generate a WordPress shortcode which will display a [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/). The shortcode function itself works like a charm; I can pass my data and the shortcode is rendered properly.

**The problem:**

In the shortcode I also added an attribute `id`, which will be used to pass an ID used to call the slider, so for example:

```
$(".myid").bxSlider({
```

So the `"myid"` part would be passed like `[myshortcode id="myid"]`. But as the script needs to be placed in the footer (using: `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myshortcode_function');`). So, I have to call the `id` attribute outside the shortcode function.

Could anybody please explain, how to pass that attribute so I can use it in another function? Please do not link me to the documentation. I read it, and I don't understand it.

Comment: `$(".myid")` is not applicable for `id=myid` use `$("#myid")` instead

Comment: Enqueue your script when the shortcode is present like suggest e.g. in this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165759/22534). Use `wp_localize_script` to pass the information you need.

Comment: @shanavasm thanks for your reply, but "id" in this case is the name of the variable, it's not meant to be a html class or id, please dont get confused.

Comment: @ialocin also thank you for your reply, i already checked if the shortcode was used to display some data, so this is checked. I just dont know how to use the localize_script option.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to read-up on it yourself.

Comment: @ialocin "i dont understand the description" - "read it yourself".... i guess you didn't read. btw: mostly a one line answer won't help anybody. at least if they want to understand, not copy and paste.... but anyway, thank you for spending your time with my issues.

Comment: What I meant is, I do not have the time to give you more then a hint. Good luck!

Comment: What about storing the variable in [wordpress cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) and retrieve it in the callback function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. WordPress have a handy function to send variables to a registered script. It's `wp_localize_script`. It work this way:

```
//First Register Your Script
wp_register_script( 'name-of-script', 'http://example.com/script.js', '', '', true );

//Then send dynamic variables
wp_localize_script( 'name-of-script', 'globalVar', array( 'id' => 'slideTarget' ) );

//Finally invoke it on Front-End
wp_enqueue_script ( 'name-of-script' );
```

This should outputted before the script is called, and since it's called on footer, you can just call it inside your shortcode function. Then, on your script, you will need to use it like this:

```
$("#" + globalVar.id ).bxSlider({
```

Simple as that. There are other options as well, like outputting a global var or outputting a hidden input with the target ID, so you script would just need to looking for that hidden input value.

Comment: thank you very much for your fast reply, but to be honest, i still dont know what to do... where to place the snippets..... especialy which script are you talking about "name of script"? Up to now i am using an echo function to display the needed code, i only need to to insert the ID automatically....

Comment: Just edited my answer to make it clear how to use the proper functions to call scripts on WordPress

Comment: Thank you @bruno-cantuaria I've tried to use it, it works like a charm for a console log function fe. But if I try to use it for the slider (like your last example) "$("#" + globalVar.id ).bxSlider({" i get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Do you have any further idea?

Comment: I have managed it (was a typo). But now, if I have multiple sliders on a page only the first will be rendered. is there a chance of a foreach-method?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just outputting the javascript directly, then you could use an anonymous function with a `use` scope:

```
    function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
        add_action( 'wp_footer', function () use ( $atts ) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javscript">
                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $(".<?php echo $atts['id']; ?>").bxSlider({
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        } );
    }
```