# wp_enqueue_script seperately for each shortcode

Tags: php, json

how can i use wp_enqueue_script seperately for each shortcode to be used?

```
function shortA()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('member', plugins_url('js/member.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}add_shortcode('shortA','shortA');


function shortB()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('nonmember', plugins_url('js/nonmember.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}add_shortcode('shortB','shortB');
```

I have tried this but no luck:
[Enqueue Scripts / Styles when shortcode is present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present)

```
function this_is_my_shortcode(){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        wp_register_script('per-pas-belanja-online', plugins_url('js/per-pas-belanja-online.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('per-pas-belanja-online');
    });
    return '<div id="poppedout">Blah</div>';
}
add_shortcode('bubba', 'this_is_my_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close!

What you can do is to register all of the scripts via the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook normally and then just enqueue them in the shortcode callback. This is telling WordPress about the scripts and then allowing you to only enqueue them as needed:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' 'register_all_my_scripts' );
function register_all_my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'per-pas-belanja-online', plugins_url('js/per-pas-belanja-online.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0' );
}

function this_is_my_shortcode(){
    wp_enqueue_script('per-pas-belanja-online');
    return '<div id="poppedout">Blah</div>';
}
add_shortcode('bubba', 'this_is_my_shortcode');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried to make it work, maybe some code doesn't work. I have tried this also but it doesn't work, maybe there is some small error in here: global $post;
if ( has_shortcode( $content, 'shortA' ) ) { 
 wp_enqueue_script('member', plugins_url('js/member.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

elseif( has_shortcode( $post->post_content 'shortB' ) ) { 
 wp_enqueue_script('nonmember', plugins_url('js/nonmember.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

Comment: I can't really read that  - can you update the original question? Also how do you know it's not working  - what kind of errors are you getting, are you sure the path is correct to the JS file?

Comment: it's only reading the 1st wp_enqueue_script('member', plugins_url('js/member.js', FILE), array('jquery'), '1.0', true); when i use the 2nd shortcode it should be wp_enqueue_script('nonmember', plugins_url('js/nonmember.js', FILE), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

Comment: You need to register both - are you doing that? If so, I'd confirm you don't have an issue with the js path, dependencies or a syntax error.

Comment: hi yes i register both, still dont know why isnt working

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing more code