# Enqueue script only when shortcode is used, with WP Plugin Boilerplate

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm building a plugin using the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate by DevinVinson](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate).

Everything works fine, except one thing:

I'm trying to enqueue scripts and css only when a shortcode is present in the page.

In `define_public_hooks` function, I added a call to the loader to register scripts instead of enqueuing them:

```
private function define_public_hooks() {
    // ...
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_register_script', $plugin_public, 'register_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_register_script', $plugin_public, 'register_scripts' );
    // ...
}
```

Then in `class-my-plugin-public.php` file I created two public functions `register_styles()` and `register_scripts()`. Inside these functions, I just register scripts and styles, instead of enqueuing them. It's something basic, like this:

```
public function register_scripts() {    
    wp_register_script( $this->plugin_name . '_google_maps_api', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='. $gmap_key .'&amp;v=3&amp;libraries=places', array( 'jquery' ), '3', true );
}
```

Then I would like to enqueue them in the shortcode return function, but they do not get registered at all.

I checked with `wp_script_is( $this->plugin_name . '_google_maps_api',  'registered' )`, and it returns `false`.

If I make the very same stuff, but with `enqueue` instead of `register` everything works fine.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why it's not working:

You need to use the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) action hook. You've used `wp_register_script` as an action hook, however, there is no action hook named `wp_register_script` in WordPress core.

If this was just a silly mistake, then you already have the answer. Read on if you need more information regarding the topic:

---

Attaching a callback function to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) [action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) doesn't mean your scripts and styles will be enqueued, it simply means when you want to execute that [callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

The original registering and enqueuing is done by functions such as: `wp_register_script()`, `wp_register_style`, `wp_enqueue_script()`, `wp_enqueue_style()` etc., not by any [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/).

> Note the difference between the role of functions and hooks:
>
> - A [**function**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) executes some CODE to accomplish predefined tasks when called.
>
>   Example: these all are WordPress core functions: `wp_register_script()`, `wp_register_style`, `wp_enqueue_script()`, `wp_enqueue_style()`.
> - A [**hook**](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) only attaches a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) function (to be executed later) at a predefined point of CODE execution.
>
>   Example: this is a WordPress core (action) hook: `wp_enqueue_scripts` - notice the `s` (plural) at the end.
>
>   ***Double check:*** `wp_enqueue_script()` is a function and `wp_enqueue_scripts` is an action hook.

## The correct CODE:

So your corrected CODE should be like:

```
private function define_public_hooks() {
    // ...
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'register_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'register_scripts' );
    // ...
}
```

Then,

```
public function register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( $this->plugin_name . '_google_maps_api', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='. $gmap_key.'&amp;v=3&amp;libraries=places', array( 'jquery' ), '3', true );
}
```

After that, you enqueue the script (& style) from within you shortcode handler function:

```
public function your_shortcode_handler( $atts ) {
    // shortcode related CODE
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '_google_maps_api' );
    // more shortcode related CODE
}
```

With this CODE, your scripts / styles enqueued from `your_shortcode_handler` function will only be added to your site when there is a shortcode in that particular URL.

### Further Reading:

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165759/110572) has an interesting discussion on enqueuing scripts & styles only when shortcode is present.

Comment: Actually i wrongly assumed that wp_register_scripts was existent (the missing "s" is a pasting error.  I updated my question with a small addition to have a 100% working code. Could tou have a look at it? I cant pass the $this->plugin_name to shortcode function.

Comment: I've posted a new question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260278/pass-this-to-function-nested-in-another-public-function-of-the-same-class and I've removed the follow up from here. Thanks, also for advices on how best ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the first argument to the `add_action` call needs to be a *WordPress* action name... So "wp_register_script", not being a WP action, is never called.

I'd suggest all you need to do, really, is add your registering calls to your plugin's enqueue_scripts function - no need to fuss with the define_public_hooks, or create a new register_scripts function. Simply go with the existing enqueue_scripts function, but add your registrations there:

```
public function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/plugin-name-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );

    // NOTICE this is a *registration* only:
    wp_register_script( $this->plugin_name.'_google_maps_api', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='. $gmap_key.'&amp;v=3&amp;libraries=places', array( 'jquery' ), '3', true ); 
}
```

Then when your short code, your script should be registered, ready to be enqueued.

Hope this helps!