# Pass $this to function nested in another public function of the same class

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm building a plugin using the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate by DevinVinson](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate).

I'm adding a public shortcode function for wich I will need some resources (js and css), I want to enqueue scripts (that go in the footer) only when necessary, so I need to enqueue scripts just before the return of the shortcode.

Thanks to [Fayaz answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259657/enqueue-script-only-when-shortcode-is-used-with-wp-plugin-boilerplate#answer-259671) I solved the main problem, but I still got a small one: I can't pass $this->plugin_name to shortcode function, variable I need to correctly name resources in the `wp_enqueue_script` function.

As the Boilerplate provide just `add_action` hooks in `define_public_hooks` function, I did use that, and nested inside it the add_shortcode hook, like this:

```
class My_Plugin {
   $plugin_public = new My_Plugin_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

   $this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'my_plugin_ajax_register_shortcode' );

}
```

then in `my-plugin-public.php` file:

```
class My_Plugin_Public {

  public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;

    }

  public function my_plugin_ajax_register_shortcode(){


     function the_actual_shortcode($atts){

        $content = 'shortcode content';

        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name.'_google_maps_api' ); // we don't know what $this->plugin_name is!

        return $content;    
     }
     add_shortcode('my_shortcode', the_actual_shortcode);
 }

}
```

As you can imagine, the `the_actual_shortcode` function, ignores `$this->plugin_name`, how can I pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. I'm showing you a way that will not fundamentally change how you are doing it:

First in `My_Plugin` class:

```
class My_Plugin {
    // ...
    private function define_public_hooks() {
        $plugin_public = new My_Plugin_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
        $this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'init' );
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then in `My_Plugin_Public` class, create a new method named `init`. Here you'll do things that you want once WordPress `init` action hook is triggered. So adding shortcode will go into this `init` method:

```
class My_Plugin_Public {

    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;

    }

    public function init() {
        add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', array( $this, 'my_plugin_ajax_register_shortcode' ) );
    }

    public function my_plugin_ajax_register_shortcode( $atts ) {
        $content = 'shortcode content';
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '_google_maps_api' );
        return $content;
    }
}
```

So, basically instead of creating an inner function within the class method `my_plugin_ajax_register_shortcode`, we are utilizing another method named `init` within the class. Now we'll be able to access `$this->plugin_name` inside the shortcode handler function, because now it's within the scope of our `My_Plugin_Public` class.

Comment: Tnx Fayaz, what about putting add_shortcode inside __construct() without creating init()? I tried and works. Are there some issues?

Comment: There are many ways you can do it. However, some WordPress core features are available only after the `init` hook is fired. So make sure you have a clear understanding of WordPress core loading order. [Answers here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hook-run-sequence) may help.