# Can't get JS code to work with shortcode

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I am trying to create a plugin and I've got stuck. I am trying to register and enqueue a script from a shortcode:

This is my shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'gear-guide', 'gg_product_front_end' );
```

This is the function it calls to:

```
function gg_product_front_end() {

    echo '<p id="test">Test!</p>';

    wp_register_script( 'gg_loadProducts_frontEnd', plugins_url( 'js/front_end.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gg_loadProducts_frontEnd' );

}
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
function gg_loadProducts_frontEnd() {
    console.log( 'Test!' );
}
```

JavaScript doesn't work, but I am not getting any error, neither php nor js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the Shortcode generated string, not `echo`, like this:

```
function gg_product_front_end() {
    wp_register_script( 'gg_loadProducts_frontEnd', plugins_url( 'js/front_end.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gg_loadProducts_frontEnd' );

    return '<p id="test">Test!</p>';
}
```

Also, you need to call the JavaScript function, like this:

```
function gg_loadProducts_frontEnd() {
    console.log( 'Test!' );
}
gg_loadProducts_frontEnd();
```

Otherwise `Test!` will not be logged in Browser Console.

Also, check [This Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/165754/110572) to enqueue Scripts / styles when shortcode is present.

Comment: Thanks! it works. I will mark as answered when I'll be able (it tells me I can  only in two more minutes)