# How can I included CSS to a page or a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, css

I would like to add CSS to a page or a shortcode (preferably a shortcode) that would not be dependent on a theme, a plug-in or anything.

I tried adding `wp_enqueue_style('[my-css-url]');` to various PHP files but without success. Yet I would expect more proper ways to do it.

I there a way to do that?

---

This question is not a duplicate of [Enqueue Scripts / Styles when shortcode is present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present)
That other question is asked and solved in the context of a plug-in. My question clearly state "independant from plug-ins".

Comment: WordPress is designed to execute custom code which leverages it's APIs via the architecture presented by plugins and themes. Slapping `wp_enqueue_style()` calls in random files is inadvisable and likely to produce undesirable side-effects - or simply erase your changes the next time WordPress updates. Make a small plugin to house your modifications, or let us discuss why you believe you cannot use a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply follow the link to the [`has_shortcode()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) documentation in the [last answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/316093/30597) to the duplicate question. There you'll find:

> ```
> function custom_shortcode_scripts() {
>   global $post;
>   if ( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'custom-shortcode') ) {
>       wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script');
>   }
> }
> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_shortcode_scripts');
> ```

For styles this would be:

```
function custom_shortcode_styles() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'custom-shortcode') ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-shortcode-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-shortcode.css');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_shortcode_styles');
```

Replace `custom-shortcode` inside `has_shortcode()` with the shortcode you are actually looking for, then put that snippet in your `functions.php` or in your plugin and code on!

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only load the CSS if the shortcode is inside the post content. If the shortcode is used in a template, widget, custom field or anything else, then the CSS won't load.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. In my case it's only used in the post content.