# How do I get rid of my inclusion race-condition on wp_enqueue_script

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying not to be a [lazy dev](https://github.com/youknowriad/wp-js-plugin-starter/issues/6). Thus I want to only include my js files where they are needed.

As the js is needed everywhere where my shortcode is used I tried to do what was answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165759/110572).

i.e.:

js

```js
function do_cool_stuff(){
    //do the most awesomest of stuff
    //..ok mostly changes textvalues dynamically
}
```

php

```php
function enqueueAllMyStuff(){
    \wp_enqueue_script('my_stuff',path_to_my_stuff);
    \wp_localize_script('my_stuff','jabba_the_slug',['url'=>\admin_url('admin-ajax.php')];
//...
}
\add_shortcode('goodName',__NAMESPACE__.'\\my_shortcode')
function my_shortcode(){
    enqueueAllMyStuff();
    return '<script>do_cool_stuff()</script>';
}
```

But that did not work. As "do_cool_stuff is not defined".
Tried to do

```php
return '<img src="'.admin_url().'/images/loading.gif" onload="do_cool_stuff()"/>';
```

Which works nicely from time to time. Implying its a race condition.

```php
function my_shortcode(){
    \add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',__NAMESPACE__.'\\enqueueAllMYStuff');
    return '<script>do_cool_stuff()</script>';
}
```

also does not work, as the headers are already send.

so... There ought to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `wp_enqueue_script()` inside a shortcode, which is essentially what you're doing by calling `enqueueAllMyStuff()`, the script is going to be queued up to be loaded in the footer. So if your shortcode runs a script as soon as it's printed, the JavaScript file that it depends on won't be available yet, and will cause this error.

The simplest solution is to update your script to wait for the document to have loaded. With jQuery you'd use `jQuery( document ).ready()`, but in vanilla JS you can use:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        do_cool_stuff();
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Just want to mention too the handy:  `wp_add_inline_script( 'my_stuff', 'do_cool_stuff();' );` right after `wp_enqueue_script( 'my_stuff' ,path_to_my_stuff)`.