# How to force that styles are enqueued in the header?

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

I have a plugin processing a shortcode, that needs specific styles.
For this I used `wp_enqueue_style`.

As I just need to enqueue the CSS **upon certain parameters of the shortcode**, I call wp_enqueue_style **inside a method launched from my shortcode entrypoint**, and not from a hook added in the plugin's constructor (I use a PHP class).

As a result, the CSS is indeed inserted, but before the `</body>` tag and not in the `<head>`, whereas if `wp_enqueue_style` is called from the constructor, the CSS is enqueued in the head.

This prevents the plugin's user from adding its own CSS for overriding mine (if it's added in the body).

Is it possible to call `wp_enqueue_style` after the plugin's class is built and having the style enqueued in the header?

Or is there another way to achieve this? My goal is to avoid enqueuing unnecessary styles (and scripts).

NB : For information I have exactly the same behavior with `wp_enqueue_script` for scripts: whether it's in the head or in the body depends on when it's called…

Thanks

**Edit:**

Here's a tiny plugin showing my shortcode plugin pattern and what I want to achieve;

```
class MyPlugin
{
    protected $myoption;

    public function __construct()
    {
            add_action('init', array($this, 'add_hooks'));
    }

        public function add_hooks()
        {
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'hook_javascript'));
            add_shortcode ('myshortcode', array($this, 'process_shortcode'));
        }

        public function hook_javascript()
    {
            global $post;
            if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' )
               && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'myshortcode') ) 
            {
        // IF ENQUEUED HERE, THE STYLE IS IN THE HEAD, BUT IT'S INSERTED UNCONDITIONNALLY
                wp_enqueue_style ('mycss', plugins_url('/js/mycss.css', __FILE__ ));
            }
        }

        protected function processParams ($atts)
        {
            $attributes = shortcode_atts( array('myoption' => NULL), $atts );
        $this->myoption = $attributes['myoption'];

        if (isset($this->myoption)) {
        // I want to enqueue the style only if 'myoption' attribute is set
        // IF ENQUEUED HERE, THE STYLE IS IN THE BODY !!!
                wp_enqueue_style ('mycss', plugins_url('/js/mycss.css', __FILE__ ));
            }
    }

        public function process_shortcode ($atts, $content = "")
        {
            // Check parameters
                $this->processParams ($atts);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a solution should be working for you [Enqueue Scripts / Styles when shortcode is present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present)

Comment: Thanks. After checking, no it doesn't : This post says that "When a shortcode is rendered, <head> section was already printed, it means that js can be added without any problem on footer, but css must be added **before** the shortcode is rendered.". So I think I'm stuck, I can't insert styles in the head upon condition. It must be inserted in each page if  want it inserted in the head....

Comment: Would like to know your shortcode using pattern. When you use the shortcode, is it in specific page? There might be some other workarounds for different patterns.

Comment: Thanks @simongcc. I edited the post to explain my code pattern.